# Drupal views UI, filter exposed, the date in collection field's content only by month and year (no day)

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-exposed-filter, drupal-field-collection

Is it possible to add an exposed filter with only month and years parameters ?
When I add this filter, the user must choose the day, the month and the year. I don't want the "day option"

The format of my date field in the content is : Month Year. 
This field is contained in a collection fields.
My content struture is like :

- content

  -some field

  -some field

  -collection fields

  ```
  - date field (format : month year)

  - some field
  ```

  ...

Comment: did u find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

When you add a date field in the Filters section, you can select the "Filter granularity". Changing it to a month will cause the filter to only expect month and a year from the user, but not the day.